# Is layoutSubviews called whenever view's size is changed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

In my impression, with autoresizesSubviews = YES, layoutSubviews should be called every time view's size is changed. But I found it is not the case for my view. Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: Sorry for my sloppiness. I mean size change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to sources at Apple,

*"-[UIView layoutSubviews] should get called when the size of the view changes."*

They also referred me to this, from the the View Programming Guide for iOS:

*"Whenever the size of a view changes, UIKit applies the autoresizing behaviors of that view’s subviews and then calls the layoutSubviews method of the view to let it make manual changes. You can implement the layoutSubviews method in custom views when the autoresizing behaviors by themselves do not yield the results you want."*

At this point, your best move is to create a small sample project where `layoutSubviews` does not get called (or, send your existing project) file a bug with Apple using [BugReporter](http://bugreport.apple.com), and include that sample project with your bug.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to create a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something to happen when your view is resized, you can also override `setBounds:` and `setFrame:` for your class to make sure it happens.  It would look something like this

```
-(void)setBounds:(GCRect newBounds) {
    // let the UIKit do what it would normally do
    [super setBounds:newBounds];

    // set the flag to tell UIKit that you'd like your layoutSubviews called
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

-(void)setFrame:(CGRect newFrame) {
    // let the UIKit do what it would normally do
    [super setFrame:newFrame];

    // set the flag to tell UIKit that you'd like your layoutSubviews called
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

The other reason that I sometimes override these methods (temporarily) is so I can stop in the debugger and see when they are getting called and by what code.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not asking what to do to force a layout — I know I can call setNeedsLayout. I'm confirming whether it is a defined protocol that whenever view's size is changed its layoutSubviews is called subsequently. I thought so but what I see in my code defies it, so I'm wondering whether it is an SKD bug or my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll ask a few friends at Apple and see what kind of answers we get.  Which version of Xcode and which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: In the meantime ... check out this [guide from developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html). It has a lot of good information about view layout.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, layoutSubviews is called when the view's **bounds** change.  This means that if its position changes in its superview (but not its size) then layoutSubviews won't be changed (since the origin point in the bounds is in the view's coordinate system - so it is almost always 0,0).  In short, only a change in size will cause this to be fired.

Comment: Sorry for my sloppiness. I mean size change. My layoutSubviews are not called even when its size is changed.

Answer (score -1):

whenever you want to resize the views manually and resizes automatically call **layoutSubViews** method

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;

    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

    CGRect frame,itemlabelframe,statuslabelframe;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+1 ,0, 97, 50);

    itemlabelframe=CGRectMake(boundsX+100, 0, 155, 50);

    statuslabelframe=CGRectMake(boundsX+257, 0, 50, 50);
    ItemDescButton.frame=itemlabelframe;


    priorityButton.frame = frame;
    statusButton.frame=statuslabelframe;
    //    ItemDescLabel.frame=itemlabelframe;
    //    statusLabel.frame=statuslabelframe;

}
```